# How to restart job after cancel in kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How to restart `job` after canceling in `kotlin coroutines`

I have 2 buttons, 1 to start coroutine and another to cancel the job.
But after I cancel the job, coroutine not starts again.

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

    private lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = SettingFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        job = Job()

        button1.setOnClickListener {
            launch {
                val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
                println(currentTime)
            }
        }

        button2.setOnClickListener {
            job.cancel()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Comment: If you decide to not use MainScope (which you should use), get rid of "get() = Dispatchers.Main + job". This will give you a new CoroutineContext every time you access it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're inappropriately using the top-level job linked to the lifecycle of the fragment as the means to cancel your coroutine on demand.

Replace this boilerplate:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

    private lateinit var job: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
```

with this:

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope by MainScope {
    override fun onDestroy() {
        cancel()
    }
```

This will automatically fix one of the problems you introduced: it uses a `SupervisorJob` instead of a plain `Job`.

Next, you need access to the job you launched in `onClick`:

```
    private var button1Job: Job?

    ...

    button1.setOnClickListener {
        button1Job = launch {
           ...
           button1Job = null
        }
```

You can now cancel this job in `button2` listener:

```
    button1Job?.cancel()
```

Comment: Why this `button1Job = null` ?

Comment: @MurilloComino quite late but... probably to free the reference to the job once it has finished, so it can be reclaimed by the GC.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the above answer, you should use

```
 button1Job.cancelChildren()
```

This retains the integrity of the job and ensures it can be relaunched after cancellation unlike cancel which affects the state of the job